# IE6 CSS List as horizontal navigation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="links">
        <li>
          <a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
    <li>
      <a href="google.com">Google</a>
        </li>                   
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.links {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.links li {
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 4px -2px;
}
```

When viewing this in IE6 the list items are 100% in width, where as I need them to be as wide as the text they contain plus the padding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.links li {
    display:inline;
}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

When you float an element you must apply a width attribute.

`width:100px; /* or whatever */`

Comment: In the context of trying to create a horizontal menu, how else would each `<li>` know how wide to be(including IE versions)?